# Google Contacts API v3 does not return system groups

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-apps-marketplace, google-shared-contacts

I found that Google Contacts API v3 does not return system groups when I fetch feed of all contacts:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
```

But if I supply v2 via GET param:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=2
```

all system groups are returned for contact entries.

Same thing when i try to fetch list of groups:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full
```

Is there another way to receive system groups?
Or v3 just does not support receiving system groups anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contacts API v3 is denoted by ?v=3. When you do not specify a version parameter you are actually using the v1 API.