# Getting Google Contacts API System Groups

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I am accessing the google contacts api successfully with:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

And getting all my groups with:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full

However, the first query is pulling back every person I have ever emailed. I want it to only pull the mycontacts group. Apparantly this is a system group that can't be deleted by the user. How do I get just the contacts in this one group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify v=3 in your query paramaters.

[Google Contacts API v3 does not return system groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413762/google-contacts-api-v3-does-not-return-system-groups)

Otherwise it interprets it as the v1 api which does not display system groups by default.

Comment: You mean, "which does display"?